# How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, accordion, javafx, javafx-2

I cannot find an answer about this anywhere on the internet.

I have an application that has to have collapsable panels, so the TitledPane and Accordion set-up in Java FX is a natural candidate.

In the application, I need to have custom headers for the container when it's collapsed.  I see in the css document for the TitledPane that the header is really an HBox and a variety of other components.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane

I would like to access this component and replace it with a custom component.

I have been using the TitledPane api's setGraphic function and setContentDisplay to GraphicOnly.  with a custom component.  However, I cannot get it to render correctly.  I've had issues with removing the arrow, and removing the space occupied by the arrow.

See the link below for screenshots of the desired look and how it actually looks.

http://tinypic.com/r/s1pxfn/6

How does one remove the arrow and remove the padding?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TitledPane is a Labeled, so you can [set a graphic](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic%28javafx.scene.Node%29) on it in a listener or a binding to the [expanded](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html#expandedProperty) property.

Changing background colors etc (including overriding styling of the :focused pseudo-class) is something that can be accomplished via css (refer to the TitledPane section of the [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) stylesheet in jfxrt.jar for examples).

If you need code based access to sub-components of the TitledPane, you can use the [lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) function after the TitledPane has been added to a Scene shown on a Stage.

```
adminPane.lookup(".arrow").setVisible(false);
```

I'd advise trying the graphic/css stylesheet based approaches before trying a lookup.

If you don't need the Labeled to display text then set it display a [graphic only](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContentDisplay.html#GRAPHIC_ONLY).

```
titledPane.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
```

Here is some sample code which displays a TitledPane with a customized header next to a TitledPane without a customized header.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx */
public class TitledPaneCustomization extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TitledPane adminPane = new TitledPane("Administration", 
      VBoxBuilder.create().style("-fx-padding: 10").spacing(10).children(
        ButtonBuilder.create().text("Admin Client").maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build(),
        ButtonBuilder.create().text("Admin User").maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build()
      ).build()            
    );
    adminPane.setAnimated(false);
    adminPane.getStyleClass().add("admin");
    Node open   = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(5).children(
      new Circle(4, 4, 8, Color.FORESTGREEN),
      new Rectangle(50, 16, Color.AQUAMARINE)
    ).build();
    Node closed = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(5).children(
      new Circle(4, 4, 8, Color.GOLDENROD),
      new Rectangle(50, 16, Color.AQUAMARINE)
    ).build();

    adminPane.graphicProperty().bind(
      Bindings
        .when(adminPane.expandedProperty())
          .then(open)
          .otherwise(closed)
    );
    adminPane.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    TitledPane viewPane = new TitledPane("View", 
      VBoxBuilder.create().style("-fx-padding: 10").spacing(10).children(
        ButtonBuilder.create().text("View Client").maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build(),
        ButtonBuilder.create().text("View User").maxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE).build()
      ).build()            
    );
    viewPane.setAnimated(false);

    VBox errorPane = VBoxBuilder.create().style("-fx-padding: 10").spacing(10).children(
      new Label("500: Aug 8, 12:15pm"), 
      new Label("404: Aug 7, 3:27am")
    ).build();
    Label nErrors = new Label();
    nErrors.getStyleClass().add("nerrors");
    nErrors.textProperty().bind(Bindings.size(errorPane.getChildren()).asString());

    TitledPane connectivityPane = new TitledPane(
      "",      
      errorPane
    );
    Label connectivityErrorLabel = new Label("CONNECTIVITY ERROR");
    connectivityErrorLabel.getStyleClass().add("connectivityErrorLabel");
    connectivityPane.getStyleClass().add("connectivity");
    connectivityPane.setAnimated(false);
    connectivityPane.setGraphic(
      HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(2).alignment(Pos.CENTER).styleClass("header").children(
        nErrors,    
        new ImageView(
          new Image(
            "http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/gallery2/open_icon_library-full/icons/png/48x48/actions/network-disconnect-2.png",
            0, 24, true, true
          )
        ),
        connectivityErrorLabel
      ).build()
    );

    HBox layout = new HBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10; -fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(adminPane, viewPane, connectivityPane);
    layout.setPrefHeight(150);
    layout.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("titledpanecustomization.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    primaryStage.show();

    Node arrow = adminPane.lookup(".arrow");
    arrow.setVisible(false);
    arrow.setManaged(false);

    // translate the titledpane arrow and header so that the arrow is displayed to right of the header.
    Pane connectivityArrow = (Pane) connectivityPane.lookup(".arrow");
    connectivityArrow.translateXProperty().bind(
      connectivityPane.widthProperty().subtract(connectivityArrow.widthProperty().multiply(2))
    );
    Pane connectivityTitle = (Pane) connectivityPane.lookup(".header");
    connectivityTitle.translateXProperty().bind(
      connectivityArrow.widthProperty().negate()
    );
  }
}
```

And some css to go with it:

```
/** titledpanecustomization.css place in same build directory as TitledPaneCustomization.java 
    and ensure build system copies it to the output classpath. */
.admin .titled-pane > .title {
  -fx-background-color: blue, yellow, linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(coral, +50%), coral);
}

.connectivity {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.nerrors {
  -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-focus-color, -15%);
  -fx-padding: 5 8 5 8;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.connectivityErrorLabel {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
  -fx-padding: 0 40 0 3; 
}

.connectivity .titled-pane > .title {
  -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
  -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0;
  -fx-padding: 0.166667em 1.166667em 0.25em 0; /* 2 14 3 0 */
  -fx-color: -fx-focus-color;
}

.connectivity .titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow {
  -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

[image: Sample customized TitledPane]

Comment: So, I did try setting a graphic on it but I can't get it to render correct.  For starters, it renders it to the right of the arrow and to the left of the text.  Is there a way to get around that, by either A) replacing the entire HBox (which houses the arrow, the text, and the graphic) or B) go above the entire HBox with the custom graphic?

Basically, if I just create a red HBox, it is placed to the right of the arrow, and the left of the text.  This is not the desired behavior and I need to get around it.

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your question what your desired behaviour is - a mockup image can help.  The TitledPane is customizable in numerous ways.  I updated my answer to include some detailed sample code.  Hopefully that should be sufficient for you to be able to achieve the customization you seek.

Comment: Wow, that was an unbelievable answer.  I will try it out and keep you posted.  I really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still having some issues with the arrow.  I have updated the original post.  Basically, this link shows where I am (on top) and where I want to be (on bottom).  Ignore styling such as text color, font, gradient background, etc.  Mainly, I want to shift everything over x pixels and get rid of the arrow and/or move the arrow to the right.

Comment: I updated the sample to include a TitledPane customization as per updated pic in the updated question.

Comment: Thank you, your css is cleaner than mine.  I will update the post.

Comment: `Pane connectivityTitle = (Pane) connectivityPane.lookup(".header");` it should be `.title` instead of `.header`, right?

Comment: Does this code example still work for you? I get different visuals, like the backgrounds of the title areas not having the assigned colors. The css is loaded fine.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(Moved answer from question)</sub>

This is the answer:

To remove the arrow, add this CSS declaration:

```
.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow{
    -fx-shape: "";
}
```

The above CSS snippet will remove the arrow, but the space for the arrow is still occupied.  This was really tricky and I couldn't find it documented anywhere on the internet, but I applied this CSS statement and it removed the gap from the arrow.

```
.titled-pane > .title{
   -fx-padding: 0 0 0 -4;
}
```

This may not be the best solution, but it is a solution that has worked for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the present day at the end of 2018 nothing of these solutions works with JavaFX of JDK 1.8. So I've working on a simple solution. You can copy this method in and utility class:

```
public static boolean hideArrow(TitledPane pane) {
    Node arrowButton = pane.lookup(".arrow-button");
    if (arrowButton == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // I don't know how with this the arrow space disappears...., but it does
    arrowButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    Parent titleRegion = arrowButton.getParent();
    titleRegion.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, MouseEvent::consume);
    titleRegion.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    ((StackPane) titleRegion).getChildren().remove(arrowButton);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you remove the arrow:

```
.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button > .arrow{
    -fx-shape: null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just makes the triangle into a rectangle.