# Change Accordion icon and position JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I use `JavaFx` with `Scene Builder`, I am new at it, I want to change icon of `accordion` and its position, like that image;
I find this **`CSS`**, but i couldn't do that;

```
.titled-pane .title{
-fx-background-radius: 30;
-fx-background-image:url('ac.jpg');
}
```

[image]

Comment: See this related Q&A [How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11765436). The accordion component has the same css selectors as a titledpane, see caspian.css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

it is easy ,just add Hbox to header and set alignement right after that add what you want(Button,ImageView)

```
  <TitledPane animated="false" collapsible="false" contentDisplay="RIGHT" layoutX="900.0" layoutY="500.0" prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="431.0" stylesheets="@menu.css" text="Message" textFill="WHITE">
    <content>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
    </content>
     <font>
        <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
     </font>
     <graphic>
        <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="352.0">
           <children>
              <ImageView fitHeight="21.0" fitWidth="18.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
     </graphic>
  </TitledPane>
```