# Transparent accordion background in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to both JavaFX and CSS. I'm using Scene Builder, and have an accordion that I want to use as a menu bar. I want the background of the accordion to either be transparent or to match the background of the page behind it, and the text to be fully opaque and a different color. Also, I do not want the arrows beside the text to appear. I've tried the various options that Scene Builder provides, but none enabled me to do either of these two things. Is this something I'll need to do with CSS, and if so, how?

Comment: JavaFX, in ver 2.2, appears to be neither very mature nor robust.  It's a very complex API, so it's no wonder.  I'm having no end of small or medium-sized issues with GUI behaviors.  For right now if you're determined to use JavaFX the best approach seems to be "just be prepared to take what you can get."

Comment: @scottb - I was getting this same impression, sadly. I want to get into developing RIAs and I'm experienced with Java, but alas it seems as though I'll have to learn something new. What alternatives would you most recommend?

Comment: There is a variety of client-side presentation APIs, I can't recommend any.  They all have strengths and weaknesses.  However, Oracle is showing no signs of losing interest in JavaFX and although their market share on the client-side and the level of maturity of their API are flagging badly ... Java remains extremely popular.  I hate JavaFX right now.  I don't despise it ... I just hate it.  But I continue to believe that it has a future as long as Oracle stays behind it.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11765436/682495) as reference. Accordion has similar CSS selectors as a TitledPane. By the way I liked JavaFX, yes it has a long way to go, yes early releases had performance issues, but it should be easy to learn and code for Java devepolers.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with css. JavaFX uses a file called caspian.css for its standard styling.
An accordion module contains titled panes that consist of a title and a content area.
To remove the background color of the content you need to overwrite the styleClass of the titled panes:

```
.accordion .titled-pane > *.content {
   -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

You could also assign a custom styleClass to your titled panes or accordion if you don't want to overwrite the style application-wide.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also set the color to transparent instead of null