# JavaFX changing header of titled pane icon

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX. In my application I am using Titled pane and I want to replace the default minimise icon location from left to right end. The thing is I am using a separate FXML file for the titled pane and it is included in the scene. I used the below css content to achieve my goal.

```
.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow {
-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
-fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
-fx-padding: 0.25em 0.3125em 0.25em 0.3125em; /* 3 3.75 3 3.75 */
-fx-collapsible: false;
-fx-shape: "";
```

At first I tried to remove the icon using the above css.

```
public class PrjExplorerController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    TitledPane titledPanePrjExplorer;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        titledPanePrjExplorer.getStylesheets().add("StyleSheet.css");
        boolean b = titledPanePrjExplorer.getStyleClass().add("titled-pane");
    }     
}
```

But this not working. I think I am using a wrong approach. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: This is such a horrible hack that I'm not prepared to propose it as an answer. You will need to execute this code once the scene is actually displayed: `Node arrowButton = titledPane.lookup(".arrow-button");` `arrowButton.translateXProperty().bind(titledPane.widthProperty().subtract(32));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: [How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx)
Specifically:

```
// translate the titledpane arrow and header so that the arrow is displayed to right of the header.
Pane connectivityArrow = (Pane) connectivityPane.lookup(".arrow");
connectivityArrow.translateXProperty().bind(
  connectivityPane.widthProperty().subtract(connectivityArrow.widthProperty().multiply(2))
);
Pane connectivityTitle = (Pane) connectivityPane.lookup(".header");
connectivityTitle.translateXProperty().bind(
  connectivityArrow.widthProperty().negate()
);
```