# how to create javaFX draggable portlet

Tags: javafx, draggable, portlet

I am trying to implement a grid with draggable portlets (internal frames) in javaFX something similar to this

www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin2/portlet_draggable.html

I tried to use jfxlabs window but couldn't arrange the windows in a container that manages them.

I there a way to hack this problem? I Need to add some kind of widgets/portlets to my root pane and allow the user to change their positions, close them....

Any ideas? hints..

Answer (score 1):

You can use HBox and VBox for the alignment. And you need to implement an approporiate mouse handler for dragging and repositioning. A SceneBuilder sample would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that...but the Titledpane doesn't behave like an internal frame(window)...maybe if I hack it to add close/minimize/seettings icons to the titebar...

Comment: You don't need to hack it, you just have to use setGraphic. There's an [example of that here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx).