# What are the advantages of putting TextField inside Button (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

In `SceneBuilder` it is possible to put `TextField` inside a `Button`:

[image]

Is it for just decorative purposes or it has some functionality like when clicking button it gets child info and so on? If it has some functionality, are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html):

> A simple button control. The button control can contain text and/or a
>   graphic.

The graphic is changeable for every subclass of [Labeled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty).

You can put any node as graphic into e. g. the button. It gives you a very high level of customization.

A good example is the [customization of the header of a TitledPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx).

As for your concrete example I see no advantage, rather a disadvantage as it's not common to have a textfield inside a button. But you nevery know with what people come up with.