# How to add two panes to TitledPane header?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add two panes to TitledPane header just like in the image where there is a green and blue box.

[image]

But when I try to do it like that, it only allows me to add one pane as ImageView when using scene builder.

Comment: Reword your question.

Comment: reworded the question

Comment: Research stackpane. I can't really help you with out sample code.

Comment: Do you use Scenebuilder?

Comment: Yes, but scenebuilder only lets me add a pane as imageview to the header of the titledpane

Comment: Just put an appropriate pane in the titled pane header, and then put the two panes you want to show in the titled pane header into that pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is concerned about how to get this done in SceneBuilder, I will keep my answer restricted to it.

You can add a HBox as a Graphic to TitledPane and then add the required nodes in it.

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<TitledPane animated="false" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" prefHeight="227.0" prefWidth="392.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <graphic>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="605.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#1be440" height="15.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="13.0" />
            <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="title" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="15.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="13.0" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets right="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </graphic>
</TitledPane>
```

This will create a window like the following :

[image]

You will note that the arrow is still on the left of the HBox. To avoid this you can hide the default arrow and add an arrow in the HBox. Then add the default arrow styling to the new arrow you just added. For more information have a look at this post - [How to change header component in TitledPane in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765436/how-to-change-header-component-in-titledpane-in-javafx?rq=1).